# How informal is "mind blowing"?

Tags: formality

I'm writing a statement letter (SOP for graduate school), and I wanted to use "mind-blowing" in a less-formal segment of my letter. Is that too informal for a personal statement or cover letter, or is it just giving a more casual/friendly tone at an acceptable level to my writing?

(I'm using "mind-blowing" as an adjective that is supposed to mean "very impressive".)

Comment: SOP defaults to "Standard Operating Procedures" for me. :)

Comment: @Lawrence well, it's an acronym for "Statement of Purpose" here. (University applicants are probably used to hearing SOP in this context)

Comment: That might be regional. These letters are not standard practice in Australia, for example.

Comment: This is totally opinion-based.  But I'd never use that in anything to do with an application for grad school.

Comment: @Lawrence Have you been to grad school?

Comment: You **do not** use informal writing for a statement of purpose. See also [writers.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris So I can answer you appropriately, I’d like to know where you’re going with your question.

Comment: @KannE Haha! Interesting perspective. :)

Comment: @Kris: Why shouldn't you be slightly informal in a statement of purpose for graduate school? You do ***not*** want to make it as dry as an academic paper (where *mind-blowing* would clearly be inappropriate). I would agree it's too informal for a cover letter.

Comment: @Kris: see for example this [academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57127/what-tone-to-use-in-the-personal-statement) question, whose accepted answer says that slightly informal expressions (which I would categorize *mind-blowing* as) are acceptable in a statement of purpose.

Comment: Unless you are applying for a position with the Merry Pranksters, no, it's too informal - Ken Babbs kind of informal - ["And just out of the blue I said, "'Tis I, the intrepid traveller, come to lead his merry band of pranksters across the nation, in the reverse order of the pioneers! And our motto will be 'the obliteration of the entire nation' ... not taken literally of course, we won't blow up their buildings, we'll blow their minds!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merry_Pranksters)

Comment: BTW, the way the question reads, I think it should be considered on topic. It's primarily about degree of formality of a phrase, with an example situation used to locate a point of reference along the formality scale. It could be improved by explicitly anchoring the example to the scale and then asking where the phrase lands relative to it. Some seem to have decided the question is about where SOPs are on the formality scale. That would probably better be handled on academia.SE

Comment: @Phil: It looks like you think *mind-blowing* is a lot closer to the informal end of the scale than I do. So the OP should probably find a slightly less informal synonym.

Comment: @PeterShor I think it remains indelibly associated with LSD and the 60s counterculture to those of a certain age.

Comment: @Lawrence No offence, no pun. I said anyone who had been to (even tried to be in) grad school would have heard of "Statement of Purpose" -- so your remark would sound rather naiive for someone of your standard.

Comment: @Kris In Australia, we use different terminology and processes. The top-tier academic institutions here are called *universities*, not *grad schools*. They usually offer both undergrad and postgrad courses. Statements of purpose here seem to be associated with visa applications by non-Australians wanting to study at Australian universities, rather than a typical document Australian students submit to universities. I appreciate your comment that no offence was intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As our English professor used to say, "When in doubt, leave it out," and the difference between being ambiguous 'on purpose' versus 'by accident' is one letter grade...at least.

So, in a way, you may have already answered your own question (in your footnote):

> (I'm using "mind-blowing" as an adjective that is **supposed to mean**
>   "very impressive".)

**Synonyms & Antonyms for mind-blowing** (per Merriam-Webster; see link below):

**Synonyms**

> breathtaking, charged, electric, electrifying, exciting, exhilarating,
>   exhilarative, galvanic, galvanizing, hair-raising, heart-stopping,
>   inspiring, intoxicating, mind-bending, mind-boggling, rip-roaring,
>   rousing, stimulating, stirring, thrilling

**Antonyms**

> unexciting

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mind-blowing

Therefore, it wouldn't be surprising if someone thought you meant very exciting (in some way) if the context is lacking or ambiguous.

Not at all to say that *very impressive*, or *overwhelmingly* so, isn't a well-known (albeit **informal**) definition of mind-blowing...

### mind-blowing

> ADJECTIVE (informal):
>
> Overwhelmingly impressive.
>
> ‘for a kid, Chicago was really mind-blowing’

**More example sentences**:

> ‘The maestro himself blows a mean horn with unbelievable energy and
>   mind-blowing skill and has the kind of stage presence so-called pop
>   idols cannot be taught.’
>
> ‘It is described as a mind-blowing journey into spectacular,
>   futuristic maze-like ‘worlds of wonder’.’
>
> ‘Support fat loss and gain more energy in the process - the benefits
>   of this amazing supplement are mind-blowing!’
>
> ‘There was - is - no question: Peter Jackson has roared back into
>   theatres with the mind-blowing Part Two of the greatest fantasy epic
>   in movie history.’
>
> ‘A work of cinema so visceral, so powerful, so incredibly mind-blowing
>   must be seen to be believed.’
>
> ‘And, then, before he knew it, another song had started up; the same
>   voice, the same wonderful, mind-blowing music.’
>
> **‘This record is impressive, but not mind-blowing.’**
>
> ‘‘We've had more corporate donations and it's just mind-blowing the
>   support we've received,’ Emma continued.’

The list goes on; they give a dozen more examples for this definition (see link below).

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mind-blowing

Just FYI, this is another definition of mind-blowing (same source):

> (of a drug) inducing hallucinations.

Example sentences:

> ‘This teaching has warped more minds than any mind blowing drug has
>   ever done.’
>
> ‘The 1960s was the decade of mind-blowing drug experimentation.’

Curiously, this is the second meaning in Oxford Dictionaries but the first in Merriam-Webster (which states that this is the meaning of its first recorded use in 1966).

In conclusion, I would say (as our professor did)...be yourself, but know your audience. Some things are *mind-blowing*. That is, the word seems less informal to me when used in its proper context, as in the example sentences above (excluding the ad for the *amazing supplement*). That being said...not everything in the 80s was *awesome* (e.g. *That was awesome, dude!*--referring to a milkshake), so I would caution you: *Mind-blowing* is the new *awesome*...I think, so I would use it sparingly. Words like those can be addictive.

Comment: "**mind-blowing** adjective *informal*" (Oxf.) note the " ***informal***".

Comment: @KannE: looking at the definitions you give, it looks like there is a difference between the British and American uses of *mind-blowing* (a surprising, but not quite mind-blowing fact).

Comment: @KannE, my point was not to second your "answer" or that I did not get the gist of your answer. I meant to say that the answer is quite there in the public domain and the Question is GR. This answer is superfluous. Beyond that it's for writingSE and/or academiaSE.

Answer (score 1):

**mind-blowing**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/252776?rskey=DiZyfJ&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) colloquial.

Frequency Band 3. (not commonly found in general text types like novels and newspapers, but at the same they are not overly opaque or obscure)

> astonishing, overwhelming; consciousness-altering (esp. as a result of
>   drug use), that ‘blows one's mind’

As in The Wall Street Journal - a prestigious news/financial magazine in the U.S.:

> 2000   Wall St. Jrnl. Jan.    Films about the future grew trippy and
>   navel-gazing, eschewing action and coherent plot for mind-blowing
>   images and wild ideas.

and

> Going back to these races is mind-blowing for me,” says Rodgers.
>   Salon Oct 17, 2018

and

> It’s not all designer brands either: Wilma & Frieda’s Cafe is a great
>   brunch spot that does a mind-blowing blackberry custard french toast.
>   The Guardian Oct 17, 2018

In AmE, rules are fluid.  As tech is a burgeoning field its usage is more prevalent.  Keep in mind your context and intended audience when using **mind-blowing**.

Comment: In the second example, the word appears in a quotation, so its presence does not really indicate what the editors of the *Salon* think about its formality. Also, the fact that the *WSJ* uses the term to characterise the images in the films about the future, does not imply that its editors would tolerate its use in other contexts, to mean nothing more than *very impressive*, which is the sense in which the OP is considering using it.